# Publishing site using Web Matrix (install SQL Server Management Objects (SMO))

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, umbraco, webmatrix

I have a problem with publishing a blog (Umbraco CMS) using web matrix. It gives me this message

> ---- Unable to start
>
> --- Please install SQL Server Management Objects (SMO)

I searched for that error to solve it but I couldnt find anything useful 
I tried to add this feature from SQL Server 2008 Installer but I found that all features are already installed in it

I also searched in MSDN but this link doesnt have much information

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162189.aspx

I hope you can help me in solving this problem . Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the required components for WebMatrix compatibility aren't installed on your server.

You can download and install them with Web Platform Installer 4.0 (Products --> Server --> IIS Recommended Configuration).

For an in-depth procedure description look at [Install Server Components](http://www.iis.net/learn/web-hosting/joining-the-web-hosting-gallery/install-server-components).